# Request for principal permission failed

Tags: wcf

I have an WCF application which I have configured for https. However I get the below error:
An exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.
Additional information: Request for principal permission failed.
```

I can access the WCF service through my browser, however when my client application calls this service, I get the above mentioned error.

This is my WCF service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class SampleService
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin Users")]
    public object PerformOperation(List<string> parameterList)
    {
    …..
    …..
    }
}
```

This is my service configuration:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>    
    <behavior name="Https.Service">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="Https.Service" name="DBAccessService">
    <endpoint address="https://SYSTEM_NAME.domain.com:444/App.Service/DBAccess.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="App.DBAccessService.IDBAccess" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
```

Client Config:

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://SYSTEM_NAME.domain.com:444/App.Service/DBAccess.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="App.DBAccessService.IDBAccess" >
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost"/>
    </identity>
</client>
```

I’m using self-signed certificates which I stored in a Trusted Root Certification folder.

I’ve tried out few things:

- When I debug, using https,  I see that    the identity is not passed (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name), which I think is the issue. The same is passed correctly with “domain\id” when using HTTP.
- Secondly, when I remove the PrincipalPermission attribute over my service, it works. However this is not a solution for me.
- I get this error both on my development box and integration box (WCF service and client are on separate servers) as well.

I've gone thru' several StackVoerflow posts and tried many combinations but no luck.